# Why my job is not starting?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

I try using JobSchedulers for my chat app (for async send message):

```
 val job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(BackgroundJobService::class.java)
                .setTag(BackgroundJobService.TASKTAG_SEND_MESSAGE)
                .setReplaceCurrent(false)
                .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                .setExtras(bundle)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 1))
                .build()
dispatcher.mustSchedule(job)
```

And add my service in manifest:

```
<service
            android:exported="false"
            android:name=".data.background.service.BackgroundJobService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
            </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I write this JobService and it not called onCreate() and not called onDestroy()

```
class BackgroundJobService : JobService() {
        companion object {
            val TASKTAG_SEND_MESSAGE = "send_message"
        }

        @Inject
        lateinit var webSocket: IRxWebSocket
        var subscribe: Disposable? = null

        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            App.appComponent.inject(this)
            subscribe = webSocket.connect().subscribe({}, {})
        }

        override fun onStartJob(job: JobParameters?): Boolean {
            return true // Debug point here
        }

        override fun onStopJob(job: JobParameters?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            subscribe?.dispose()
        }
    }
```

But my onStartJob not calling! Where is my mistake?
Something i see message "Google Play services has stopped".

Comment: you don't have any semi colons `;`?!

Comment: @Omar This is Kotlin code.

Comment: I was just asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest declaration is wrong: you need to declare job services as requiring a specific permission that only the OS itself can use.  From [the JobService documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html#PERMISSION_BIND):

> Job services must be protected with this permission:
>
> > `<service android:name="MyJobService"
> >                  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >`
>
> If a job service is declared in the manifest but not protected with this permission, that service will be ignored by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I must put in bundle with

```
bundle.putString("TAG", gson.toJson(object))
```

but not

```
bundle.putParcelable("TAG", object)
```